# Applying threshold on specific vertices' weight

Tags: r, plot, filter, igraph

Given the dataframe:

```
> dput(rel.matrix)
structure(list(from = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "D", "D", "D", "D", "E", "E", "E", 
"E", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "G", "G", "G", "G", "H", "H", 
"H", "H", "I", "I", "I", "I", "J", "J", "J", "J", "K", "K"), 
    to = c("B", "C", "D", "E", "A", "C", "D", "E", "A", "B", 
    "D", "E", "F", "K", "A", "B", "C", "E", "A", "B", "C", "D", 
    "C", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "F", "H", "I", "J", "F", "G", 
    "I", "J", "F", "G", "H", "J", "F", "G", "H", "I", "C", "F"
    ), weight = c(0.09137056, 0.2677665, 0.09137056, 0.09137056, 
    0.09137056, 0.09517766, 0.02284264, 0.02284264, 0.2677665, 
    0.09517766, 0.09517766, 0.09517766, 0.3730964, 0.1675127, 
    0.09137056, 0.02284264, 0.09517766, 0.02284264, 0.09137056, 
    0.02284264, 0.09517766, 0.02284264, 0.3730964, 0.09517766, 
    0.09517766, 0.2677665, 0.09517766, 0.1675127, 0.09517766, 
    0.02284264, 0.09137056, 0.02284264, 0.09517766, 0.02284264, 
    0.09137056, 0.02284264, 0.2677665, 0.09137056, 0.09137056, 
    0.09137056, 0.09517766, 0.02284264, 0.02284264, 0.09137056, 
    0.1675127, 0.1675127)), row.names = c(NA, -46L), class = "data.frame")
```

and two sets of nodes

```
> dput(soi)
c("A", "I", "G")
> dput(all_nodes)
c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K")
```

I'm having the following function that, applies a threshold on the weights' nodes, gives different node's color between the nodes of `soi` and `all_nodes` variables and finally, plots the graph out.

The thing now is that as you can see, the threshold is applied to all of the nodes' weights regardless of the set (`soi` OR `all_nodes`) they belong to. That has as the result to remove vertices from the plot that belong to `soi` set and that is something that I don't want.

Actually, I want to plot out all the vertices that belong to `soi` set and filter using the `threshold` only the ones that don't belong to `soi` which are the `setdiff(all_nodes,soi)`.

Here is the function.

```
graph_rel_network <- function ( rel.matrix, nodes.names, soi.names, threshold )
{
  # setup vertices meta data which contain soi and not soi
  meta <- cbind( nodes.names, issoi = nodes.names %in% soi.names )

  # read in a graph: the weights are in the edge attributes
  g <- igraph::graph_from_data_frame(rel.matrix, directed = TRUE, vertices =  meta)
  g <- as.undirected(g, mode = "collapse")
  # rescale weights
  E(g)$weight2 <- 9 * E(g)$weight / max(E(g)$weight)

  # remove edges acoarding to the threshold
  g_sub <- delete.edges(g, E(g)[weight2 <= threshold ])

  # remove vertices with 0 degree
  g_sub <- delete.vertices(simplify(g_sub), degree(g_sub)==0)

  # color vertices that belongs to soi
  V(g_sub)$color <- ifelse(V(g_sub)$issoi == TRUE, "gold", "tomato")

  # plot the graph
  plot.igraph( g_sub,
               edge.width=E(g_sub)$weight2,
               vertex.label.dist=0,
               vertex.frame.color="gray",
               vertex.label.color="black")

  legend(x=-1.5, y=-1.1,
         c("Nodes of interest","Most Relevant nodes"),
         pch=21,
         pt.bg= c('gold','tomato'),
         pt.cex=2,
         cex=1,
         bty="n",
         ncol=1)

}
```

For example, you can execute `graph_rel_network( rel.matrix, all_nodes, soi, 3)`

and in the final plot node, `G` will not be appeared while it belongs to `soi`.

Is there any way NOT to filter the `soi` nodes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To retain all `soi` nodes you just need to add a bit of logic to the `delete.vertices` call:

```
graph_rel_network <- function (rel.matrix, nodes.names, soi.names, threshold )
{
  # setup vertices meta data which contain soi and not soi
  ###changed meta to a data.frame so that issoi is stored as logical instead of character
  meta <- data.frame(nodes.names, issoi = nodes.names %in% soi.names )  
  # read in a graph: the weights are in the edge attributes
  g <- igraph::graph_from_data_frame(rel.matrix, directed = TRUE, vertices =  meta)
  g <- as.undirected(g, mode = "collapse")

  # rescale weights
  E(g)$weight2 <- 9 * E(g)$weight / max(E(g)$weight)

  ###Create a subnetwork of soi nodes only
  g_soi  <- induced_subgraph(g, vids = V(g)[V(g)$name %in% soi.names])
  # remove edges acoarding to the threshold
  g_sub <- delete.edges(g, E(g)[E(g)$weight2 <= threshold])

  # remove vertices with 0 degree
  g_sub <- delete.vertices(g_sub, (degree(g_sub)==0 & !V(g)$issoi))

  ###Merge the tresholded allnode network with the soi network
  g_merge <- union(g_sub, g_soi)

  ###Resolve some attribute naming conflicts from the merge
  E(g_merge)$weight2 <- colMeans(rbind(E(g_merge)$weight2_2, E(g_merge)$weight2_1), na.rm = T)
  # color vertices that belongs to soi
  V(g_merge)$color <- ifelse(V(g_merge)$issoi_1, "gold", "tomato")

  # plot the graph
  plot.igraph( g_merge,
               edge.width=E(g_merge)$weight2,
               vertex.label.dist=0,
               vertex.frame.color="gray",
               vertex.label.color="black")

  legend(x=-1.5, y=-1.1,
         c("Nodes of interest","Most Relevant nodes"),
         pch=21,
         pt.bg= c('gold','tomato'),
         pt.cex=2,
         cex=1,
         bty="n",
         ncol=1)

}
```

[image]

Comment: Can this be done for the edges too? Because `G` is connected with`I`

Comment: But `G--I` does not have a weight >= 3

Comment: Exactly. I don't want the edges of the `soi` set be tested for that threshold. I need them to the graph either they pass or not the threshold test.